# Is decrypting tls/ssl traffic still possible on Debian?

Tags: debian, ssl

As explained by Mozilla [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/security/nss/legacy/key_log_format/index.html) and according to [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=842292) Debian bug report, exporting the SSLKEYLOGFILE variable is no longer creating a key log file. This functionality can be re-enabled at compile time but apparently not on Debian.

Is there still a way for Debian users to obtain what's needed to decrypt their own traffic?